# Get Categories and Subcategories Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue getting the subcategories from the same table, the subcategories have a parentid that represent the main category.

Where i'm wrong ?

My structure is the next.

Controller:

```
$cats = $this->categories_model->getCategories();
     foreach($cats as $ct){
         $cat_id = $ct->id;
     }
$data['categories'] = $this->categories_model->getCategories();
$data['subcategories'] = $this->categories_model->getSubcategories($cat_id);
```

Model:

```
public function getCategories() {

        $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('visible' => 1, 'parentid' => 0));
        return $query->result();
    }
    function getSubcategories($cat_id) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where(array('parentid' => $cat_id, 'visible' => 1));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

View:

```
<h4>Categories</h4>
          <div class="list-group categories">
          <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . '/products/catalog_list/' . $category->id ; ?>" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $category->name ; ?><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
            <div class="list-subgroups">
              <a href="<?php echo $subcategory->id; ?>" class="list-subgroup-item"><?php echo $subcategory->name; ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </div>
```

Table data:

```
id  parentid    name    description metatags    visible 
1   0   Boots   Boots   boots   1
2   1   Man boots   man boots   NULL    1
3   1   Women boots women boots NULL    1
5   0   Jackets Jackets NULL    1
6   5   Women jackets   Women jackets   NULL    1
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$cat_id` has a value?

Comment: Yes, has value, but is strange that has only 1 value, and i have 2 ids in array.

Comment: I have added the table structure and data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going wrong in your controller. You currently have

```
$cats = $this->categories_model->getCategories();
    foreach($cats as $ct){
        $cat_id = $ct->id;
    }
$data['categories'] = $this->categories_model->getCategories();
$data['subcategories'] = $this->categories_model->getSubcategories($cat_id);
```

You are assigning `$cat_id` and doing nothing with it inside your `foreach` loop. You are only using the last category id to select the subcategories.

You are going to want to rearrange your code so that you can get all of the sub categories for your current categories.

This may involve a little more than just putting your subcategory selection code into the loop, because you would then be overwriting your variable each time, having a similar effect.

Comment: So, in this case will be good to create another table with SubCategories ?

Comment: That is up to you. There is nothing wrong with iterative data, assuming it is setup correctly. You could also just append to the array that you would be returning.